# how to run sql file automatically? I have these files

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, hibernate

Is there any sofeware or plug-ins that can help run these files automatically? Actually I have a demo which is given by someone. It is a zip file which can be imported into eclipse. It is related to hibernate. Within the whole project, there is a folder contains a batch of sql files.

They are "CREAT_DATABASE.sql", "00_CREATE_OBJECTS.sql", "00_DROP_OBJECTS.sql", "01_ACCOUNT.sql" and "02_HIBERNATE_UNIQUE_KEY.sql"

I am wondering that is there any way to run these automatically? since the file names are some kinds of indicators that can help some software to run them according to the names. If yes, which one can do that kind of job? If no, are the file names only used to tell the users which sql file is the first to run and so forth? why don't the owner merge all the sql commands into one file?

thanks a lot for your help

while I cannot add image due to the "spam prevention mechanism" here is the image link if you want to see that. http://www2.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~11501579g/portal/img/Capture.PNG

It includes two databases, I can use either one of them as long as I set the right properties like "hibernate.connection.driver_class", "hibernate.connection.url" etc in the hibernate.cfg.xml. Actually the only problem is I DO NOT konw the way to run the sql files like I mentioned before, namely run them automatically based on the file names, though I can run sql commands one by one which are extracted from the sql files to create tables and so forth.

Comment: Can you post a screen-shot of your eclipse project-directory-structure, that is the package view of eclipse.

Comment: I have add some details I met, including the image. thanks for your kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Why make things complicated with plugins? I suggest you to use a batch file or a bash script to run these sql commans in order you need against the database you need.

Comment: Its not qite clear what you want to achieve and why so its hard to help you.